# How to make buy signals dependent on TP / SL conditions?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm pretty new to Pine Script and I'd appreciate your help here. Below is a sample code, which generates "buy" signals. However, I'd like to make these "buy" signals happen only when "take profit" or "stop loss" conditions have been met. Any idea?

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)
EMA1 = ta.ema(close, 20)
EMA2 = ta.ema(close, 50)
Buy = ta.crossover(EMA1, EMA2)
TPline = ta.valuewhen(Buy, close * 1.05, 0)
SLline = ta.valuewhen(Buy, close * 0.95, 0)
TakeProfit = ta.crossover(high, TPline)
StopLoss = ta.crossunder(low, SLline) 

plot(TPline, color=color.orange, linewidth=2)
plot(SLline, color=color.aqua, linewidth=2)
plotshape(Buy, title = "Buy", style=shape.labelup, color=color.olive, location = location.belowbar, text ="Buy", textcolor = color.white)
plotshape(TakeProfit, title = "TakeProfit", style=shape.labeldown, color=color.green, location = location.abovebar, text ="TP", textcolor = color.white)
plotshape(StopLoss, title = "StopLoss", style=shape.labelup, color=color.red, location = location.belowbar, text ="SL", textcolor = color.white)
```

Here is a screenshot as well:
[screenshot, arrow pointing to redundant buy signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tK4xh.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
plotshape(TakeProfit or StopLoss ? Buy : na , title = "Buy", style=shape.labelup, color=color.olive, location = location.belowbar, text ="Buy", textcolor = color.white)
```

or, same as

```
// put the `Buy` variable after declaration of `TakeProfit` and `StopLoss` variables 
Buy = ta.crossover(EMA1, EMA2) and TakeProfit and StopLoss

plotshape(Buy, title = "Buy", style=shape.labelup, color=color.olive, location = location.belowbar, text ="Buy", textcolor = color.white)
```

Comment: DOESN'T WORK, since all signals (Take Profit, Buy, and Stop Loss) are interdependent.