# How to make my buy signals dependent on TP / SL conditions?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I'm pretty new to Pine Script. Below is a sample code, which generates "buy" signals. However, I'd like to make these "buy" signals happen only when "take profit" or "stop loss" conditions have been met. What can I try?

[image]

I want to plot buy/sell signals after reaching profit from previous signal gain, so as not to have repaints on smaller charts.

But I made this code that only shows the signals after 19 candles.

I'm trying to find a solution so that buy/sell signals appear after I already have a take or stop from the previous signal

There is no error in my code it's just not doing a function I want.

This is my code:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

var cnt = 0
var startCounting = false

var cnt1 = 0
var startCounting1 = false

src = hlc3


atrPeriod = input(10, "ATR Length")
factor = input.float(2.99, "Factor", step = 0.01)

[supertrend, direction] = ta.supertrend(factor, atrPeriod)

bodyMiddle = plot((open + close) / 2, display=display.none)
upTrend = plot(direction < 0 ? supertrend : na, "Up Trend", color = color.green, style=plot.style_linebr)
downTrend = plot(direction < 0? na : supertrend, "Down Trend", color = color.red, style=plot.style_linebr)

fill(bodyMiddle, upTrend, color.new(color.green, 90), fillgaps=false)
fill(bodyMiddle, downTrend, color.new(color.red, 90), fillgaps=false)

//Stoch Inputs
smoothK = input.int(3, 'K', minval=1)
smoothD = input.int(3, 'D', minval=1)
lengthRSI = input.int(14, 'RSI Length', minval=1)
lengthStoch = input.int(14, 'Stochastic Length', minval=1)

upperlimit = input.float(83, 'Upper Limit', minval=0.01)
lowerlimit = input.float(17, 'Upper Limit', minval=0.01)

//Stochastic Code
rsi1 = ta.rsi(src, lengthRSI)
k = ta.sma(ta.stoch(rsi1, rsi1, rsi1, lengthStoch), smoothK)
d = ta.sma(k, smoothD)

sh = ta.crossover(k, d)
lg = ta.crossunder(d, k)

long = direction > 0 ? na : supertrend and sh and lowerlimit and d[0] < lowerlimit
short = direction < 0 ? na : supertrend and lg and upperlimit and d[0] > upperlimit

//condiçoes long
startCounting := long ? true : startCounting  // 
cnt := startCounting ? cnt + 1 : cnt    // 

canlong = long and cnt > 19
cnt := canlong ? 0 : cnt     //

//condiçoes short
startCounting1 := short ? true : startCounting1  //
cnt1 := startCounting1 ? cnt1 + 1 : cnt1

canshort = short and cnt1 > 19
cnt1 := canshort ? 0 : cnt1    


plotshape(canlong, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, text="Buy", size=size.small)
plotshape(canshort, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, text="Short", size=size.small)

// User Options to Change Inputs (%)
stopPer = input.float(4, title='Stop Loss %') / 100
takePer = input.float(0.7, title='Take Profit 1 %') / 100

//detect what was last signal (long or short)
long_short = 0
long_last = canlong and (nz(long_short[1]) == 0 or nz(long_short[1]) == -1)
short_last = canshort and (nz(long_short[1]) == 0 or nz(long_short[1]) == 1)
long_short := long_last ? 1 : short_last ? -1 : long_short[1]

//entry price
longPrice = ta.valuewhen(long_last, close, 0)
shortPrice = ta.valuewhen(short_last, close, 0)

//fixed sltp prices
longStop = longPrice * (1 - stopPer)
shortStop = shortPrice * (1 + stopPer)
longTake = longPrice * (1 + takePer)
shortTake = shortPrice * (1 - takePer)

//plot sltp lines
plot(long_short == 1 ? longStop : na, style=plot.style_linebr, color=color.new(color.red, 0), linewidth=1, title='Long Fixed SL')
plot(long_short == -1 ? shortStop : na, style=plot.style_linebr, color=color.new(color.red, 0), linewidth=1, title='Short Fixed SL')
plot(long_short == 1 ? longTake : na, style=plot.style_linebr, color=color.new(color.green, 0), linewidth=1, title='Long Fixed TP')
plot(long_short == -1 ? shortTake : na, style=plot.style_linebr, color=color.new(color.green, 0), linewidth=1, title='Short Fixed TP')

//remove first bar for SL/TP (you can't enter a trade at bar close THEN hit your SL on that same bar)
longBar1 = ta.barssince(long_last)
longBar2 = longBar1 >= 1 ? true : false
shortBar1 = ta.barssince(short_last)
shortBar2 = shortBar1 >= 1 ? true : false

//check for SL hit during a bar
longSLhit = long_short == 1 and longBar2 and low < longStop
plotshape(longSLhit, style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.gray, 0), size=size.tiny, title='Stop', text=' Stop', textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))
shortSLhit = long_short == -1 and shortBar2 and high > shortStop
plotshape(shortSLhit, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.gray, 0), size=size.tiny, title='Stop', text=' Stop', textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))

//check for TP hit during bar
longTPhit = long_short == 1 and longBar2 and high > longTake
plotshape(longTPhit, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.purple, 0), size=size.tiny, title='take 1', text='take 1', textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))

shortTPhit = long_short == -1 and shortBar2 and low < shortTake
plotshape(shortTPhit, style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.purple, 0), size=size.tiny, title='take 1', text='take 1', textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))


//reset long_short if SL/TP hit during bar
long_short := (long_short == 1 or long_short == 0) and longBar2 and (longSLhit or longTPhit) ? 0 : (long_short == -1 or long_short == 0) and shortBar2 and (shortSLhit or shortTPhit) ? 0 : long_short
```

Comment: Exact copy-paste duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72440407/how-to-make-buy-signals-dependent-on-tp-sl-conditions

Comment: Emely, if you are operating duplicate accounts, please have them merged - it is generally better for readers to be able to see your posting history than for you to create a new account for each question.

Comment: yes i copied this question because this question didn't have an answer and i wanted the answer

Comment: the script is mine and the print and the question below it is mine

Comment: but I don't have a duplicate account this is the only one

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare `var allowNewPosition = true`
2. Change your conditions: `canlong = long and cnt > 19 and allowNewPosition`and `canshort = short and cnt1 > 19 and allowNewPosition`
3. After that somewhere insert the following:

   ```
   if canlong or canshort

       allowNewPosition := false
   ```

   to activate your blocking condition after you've received your buy/sell signal
4. Finally after you know if you have a TP/SL, release the blocking of new positions:

   ```
   if longSLhit or shortSLhit or longTPhit or shortTPhit

       allowNewPosition := true
   ```

Comment: thank you very much, you helped me a lot, i love you brother